# java.util.Calendar's getFirstDayOfWeek() method gives next week's Monday instead of current week's Monday

Tags: android

I have an abstract class called CalendarUtil.java and here it is:

```
// self explanatory
public static Calendar getToday() {       
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    clearTime(calendar);
    return calendar;
}
// here I am trying to get the first day of the current week which is MONDAY
public static Calendar getFirstDayOfWeek() {
    Calendar calendar = getToday();
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY;
    return calendar;
}
// sets the date to 00:00:00:0 
public static void clearTime(Calendar c) {
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
}
```

The purpose of the `Calendar getFirstDayOfWeek()` method is to give me a `Calendar` object which is set to the current week's **MONDAY**. Say, today is Wednesday, October 10th 2018 and the method should give me a Calender set to *Monday, October 8th, 2018". Here is the problem I am facing: the method `Calendar getFirstDayOfWeek()` returns weird Calendar on SUNDAYs on one particular phone (model name: "T60" of ZTE company [Android Lollipop]). When I run the code on Sunday October 7th, it was supposed to give me a calendar set to previous week's Monday (October 1st) but it returned this weeks Monday (October 8th).

I tested it on Samsung S7 (Oreo) and Samsung Note 3 and Note 5 (Marshmellow), but the code worked fine on them.

I debugged the code on all these devices but on that particular phone instead of returning the previous week's Monday, it is giving me Monday of the upcoming week.

**Question:** Is the problem in code, or in the device? If the latter, don't the devices use the same Java library?

By the way, I am currently in Istanbul. The time zone of the devices I used set to "GMT +03:00 Turkey Istanbul".

Comment: I am no Android or Java expert but you should edit the title and have a more specific title than "java.util.Calendar is acting weird" so that future people with this problem know excatly where to go and people who can help know instantly what the question is about. [Please see the how to ask section for help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), thank you

Comment: Is using `java.util.Calendar` a requirement for your project? Other date/time libraries exist that are much better.

Comment: I am actually new to Android Development, I am not that familiar with other date/time libraries. Googled some of them, one particular 'java.time' got my attention, but some of them say that it only works above SDK=24. My current projects min SDK is 21. That's why I am not sure what to do. If there are other date/time libraries that work with Lollipop and above, that would be great to know.